# Chart JS not working with large dataset but when I have small amount of data chart is working fine

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, salesforce, lwc

I am using chart js in LWC and I have data which have more than 3000 records and more than 500 labels.

`

```
getData() {
            labels: this.uniqueLabels,
            datasets: data: this.data,
           
    }
```

```
getScales() {
        this.scalesProps = {
            yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display:false
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    
                },
                ticks: {
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontColor: '#000',
                    fontStyle: "bold",
                    beginAtZero: true,
                  },
                  maxBarThickness: 30,
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display:true
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontColor: '#000',
                    fontStyle: "bold"
                }
            }],
 
        }
```

`

this.data have 4000 records and this.uniqueLabels have 2500 records But when the chart is not rendered showing something like this (Plz refer attchaed image)

[Chart JS Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsI4r.png)

Nothing will be rendered and shows something sad emoticon.

but when I open console through inspect in browser and then reload the chart rendered properly. Also If i have samll data like around 1000 records charts work properly. Plese help me with this.

I am expecting that chart will rendered smoothly witout any restriction on amount of data to be display.

Comment: misprinted the code in getData() {
            labels: this.uniqueLabels,
            datasets: this.data,
           
    }

Comment: Could you share a bit more code ? Like the part where you instantiate the chart. It probably has to do with component life-cycle. Also there is an edit button if you need to correct your initial question.